# React.memo and withRouter

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-memo

I want to not re-render my component on certain paths, trying to do this using React.memo and checking the current path using the withRouter HOC.

The compare function in React.memo does not get called.

```
function compare(prevProps, nextProps) {
  console.log(prevProps,nextProps)
  return (prevProps.location.pathname !== '/' && nextProps.location.pathname !== '/')
}
export default React.memo( withRouter(MyComponent), compare);
```

Comment: From the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) on `React.memo`: This method only exists as a performance optimization. Do not rely on it to “prevent” a render, as this can lead to bugs.

Comment: *Why* are you trying to prevent rerenders though? Some other underlying issue? Perhaps there's some other way to structure your components so a specific one isn't rendering unnecessarily.

Comment: To optimise, I must prevent unwanted re-renders. The compare function has that specific purpose - to check if there's a need for rendering. But I can't get to invoke it.

Comment: You should [use the hooks](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Hooks) in MyComponent because [withRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter) does not re render unless parent re renders.

Comment: @HMR thanks for the answer. The problem to not render still remains since memo cannot access state values.

Comment: I guess I should be more blunt... is there some issue with extra render cycles that is compelling you to optimize `MyComponent`? I.E. are some components slow because they are remounting? Is there a component rendering a really long list?

Answer (score 3):

just use it like this

```js
function compare(prevProps, nextProps) {
  console.log(prevProps,nextProps)
  return (prevProps.location.pathname == nextProps.location.pathname)
}
export default withRouter(React.memo(MyComponent, compare));
```

##### Take care for the comparison you are about to do

the comparison you had has a flow, if you are in the main page where the route is `/` then the compare function will always return `false` causing re-render all the time(just like if `memo` didn't exist in the first place), and if your are in a sub-route other than `/` like `/articles` then the comparison will always return `true` causing the component to re-render al the time, just like if `memo` didn't exist in the first place.

What you want is a comparison that depends on `new` and `old` props having `equal` things which leads to save a re-render or having non-equal things which leads to a new re-render to render the fresh data for you.

So the comparison should be something like

```js
prevProps.location.pathname == nextProps.location.pathname
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your question, it was very helpful to me two months ago.

`memo` function take a component and a `function` that will be called to decide if React needs to re-render or not, if the function returns `true` the component will not re-render, any way if the function returns `false` then the props are now different and React do `re-render` to your component.

Now: to access the `pathname` correctly in the `function` passed to `memo` then `memo` should be wrapped with `withRouter` and not the opposite, `withRouter` wrap a component (it doesn't know it's memorized version of a component or not, it just wraps it) and pass it the routing props.

The `function` passed to `memo` as a second argument now can access the `previous` and `new` props and do the comparison as we talked earlier (where each props as inside it the fully routing details that you want).

```js
import { memo } from 'react';

function propsAreEqualBasedOnPathname(prevProps, nextProps) {
    return prevProps.location.pathname == nextProps.location.pathname;
}

withRouter(memo(MyComponent), propsAreEqualBasedOnPathname);
```

Finally, take extra care for how the comparison is made inside the `compare function` because some mistakes might prevent your component from re-rendering in the future forever.

I found using `memo` with `withRouter` really important to improve the `performance` of React components, especially if the component was a page full of details and fetching logic that can cost you some time to render, so every re-render you save, **increases your page performance**.

Comment: Need to know how to do this with React Router v6 as there is no more `withRouter` component in V6.